# IOS - How to store data into CoreData from multiple textField input at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, entity

I have an entity named Contacts, in which I want to store the name and number of two persons.

I have four textFields in my viewController( `textField1,textField2,textField3,textField4` ). In textField 1 and 2, the name and number of first person will be entered, and in textField 3 and 4, the name and number of second person will be entered. Now, when I click saveButton, the data entered in all four textFields should be stored into the entity named 'Contacts'. That is, name and number of two persons should be stored into the entity.

Using the following code, it stores the data that is entered in `textField3` and `textField4` alone.

```
@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any)
{
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let phoneContactsObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Contacts", into: context)


    phoneContactsObject.setValue(textField1.text, forKey: "name")
    phoneContactsObject.setValue(textField2.text, forKey: "number")

    phoneContactsObject.setValue(textField3.text, forKey: "name")
    phoneContactsObject.setValue(textField4.text, forKey: "number")

    do
    {
        try context.save()
        print("saved")
    }
    catch
    {

    }

}
```

How can I store data entered in all four textFields into the entity, at the same time, when the saveButton is clicked.

Using Xcode 8.2, Swift 3.0

Comment: you should always use unique key name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the value for name and number twice on the same entity. The second time you do this, you are wiping out the values you set the first time. To put it another way, name and number can only contain one value at a time.

The best solution to this depends on what your data model looks like. A first attempt to fix your problem is to create a second Contacts entity, phoneContactsObject2, and set its name and number to the values of text fields 3 and 4. This will save both sets of names and numbers to Core Data.

Beyond that, you should consider how these Contacts are related to each other and to any other entities in your model.

Comment: Is that the only way with CoreData ? in case of storing 5 persons name and number at same time, i would need to create 5 entity!!. Can i achieve this using firebase ?

Comment: Why are you worried about storing 5 entities? Think of a person as an entity. If you want to store 5 persons, you need 5 entities.

Comment: Okey. .Thanks for the idea.